# Installing a Wacom Bamboo One Pen (CTE-460)

Tags: installation, wacom, graphics-tablet

I've been looking around and following guides to get it working, but haven't gotten anything that works.

Here's some information:

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 056a:006a Wacom Co., Ltd
```

`dmesg | tail` (disconnecting and reconnecting the tablet):

```
[ 1932.290102] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, address 2
[ 1936.260109] usb 3-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
```

`lsmod | fgrep wacom`:

```
wacom                  41557  0
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux cheddar 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 19:02:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I take it you're using Ubuntu 11.04, right? Have you had a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver?

Comment: Yes, I'm running 11.04. I've looked at those links before, but they haven't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your tablet isn't supported in 11.04. Both the kernel wacom module and the x11 input driver are missing references to the model of wacom you've shown. If the kernel module ws working for this device you'd see somrthing like this:

```
[420349.922] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Intuos3 4x6 (/dev/input/mouse2)
[420349.922] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
[420349.923] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Intuos3 4x6 (/dev/input/event9)
[420349.923] (**) Wacom Intuos3 4x6: Applying InputClass "evdev tablet catchall"
[420349.923] (**) Wacom Intuos3 4x6: Applying InputClass "Wacom class"
[420349.923] (**) Wacom Intuos3 4x6: always reports core events
[420349.923] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
```

In your /var/log/Xorg.0.log file as you plug and unplug the device. Please do add anything from this log into your question just to make sure.

To get your device working, you will either have to upgrade to 11.10 or create (or ask for one to be made) a wacom-dkms package and updated companion xf86-input-wacom package which I created for 10.10 and 10.04 for wacom tablets that started working in 11.04. (if all that makes sense)